# Problema con base de datos MariaDB, tablas InnoDB, las consultas se quedan bloqueadas

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mariadb, innodb

Desde hace unas semanas estoy teniendo problemas con una de mis bases de datos, todas las consultas realizadas se quedan bloqueadas y tardan mucho en ejecutarse, sin importar en qué tabla se realicen (Incluso consultas como `SHOW PROCESSLIST` son lentas)

Esto sucede siempre una vez por hora y en el mismo minuto, aunque algunas veces también ocurre en algún otro momentos, el bloqueo suele durar entre unos segundos y varios minutos.

También he comprobado que el proceso de mysql aumenta el uso de uno de los núcleos de la cpu al 100% (De 4 núcleos).

De momento he probado lo siguiente para encontrar la causa del problema, pero sin ningún resultado.

> - Probé a desactivar todos mis trabajos cron durante al menos un día, para ver si era este el problema, pero no hubo diferencia.
> - He probado con SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, pero tampoco muestra ningún Deadlock.
> - Con SHOW PROCESSLIST solo veo las consultas bloqueadas, y no encuentro ninguna que pueda estar ocasionando el bloqueo.

Mi version de `MariaDB es: 10.2.14`, las tablas son `InnoDB`.

**Actualización 13-05-2018**

Hoy he probado a desactivar la caché de mysql con `query_cache_type=0`, pero el problema persiste.

Como me han comentado en los comentarios, he probando a utilizar `innotop`, no veo que este ocurriendo ningún Deadlock, pero sí muestra un aumento de las tablas abiertas y consultas, dejo algunas capturas.

RowOps, Open Tables y InnoDb Txns:

[image: RowOps, Open Tables y InnoDb Txns]

RowOps, Open Tables y InnoDb Txns 2:

[image: RowOps, Open Tables y InnoDb Txns 2]

Query List y InnoDb Txns:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí pueden ver la subida del `load avg` en `ttyload`

[image: ttyload]

Iré haciendo más pruebas.

**Actualización 17-05-2018**

Al final llegué a la conclusión de que era un problema del servidor (VPS 4CPU 8G), probé ha analizar todas las consultas que se realizaban durante el bloqueo con un script y siempre era una consulta diferente la primera en bloquearse, los scripts PHP que no utilizaban Mysql también se colgaban.

Después de un cambio de servidor el problema ya no está.

Ahora pude comprobar que el antiguo servidor sigue colgándose solo, sin ninguna visita, dejo una captura de munin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: fijate si esta app te da alguna pista extra https://github.com/innotop/innotop

Comment: He estado probando `innotop` pero sigo detectar el problema, también he actualizado el tema con capturas del momento en el que se produce el bloqueo.